# Delete a folder from a git PR

Tags: git, pull-request

I want to delete an entire folder from a git PR. I have mistakenly committed and pushed this folder to my branch. I don't want this as a part of my PR.

Is there a way to do this easily for a whole folder, instead of induvidually doing it for each file.

Comment: were the files in the directory added in the last revision of your branch?

Comment: @eftshift0 - yes it was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files were added in the last revision:

```
git rm -r --cached the-directory # so that the files are removed from index but kept in the working tree
git commit --amend --no-edit # fix the last revision so that the files are not there anymore
# you might need to force-push your branch now
git push -f HEAD # push this branch to its upstream
```

You should also consider ignoring the files as well so that you don't add them by mistake later.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command for removing folder in the GIT
git -rm -r